# Access BigQuery from docker image

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Trying to achieve a POC where I need to access Google BigQuery data in python data frame.

I can connect to BigQuery by simply using the below code, as I already setup gcloud auth in local gcloud SDK

```
client = bigquery.Client()
```

What is the best way to create this client in the production environment if I want to access the BigQuery in the docker image?

Where should service account key file needs to be stored? as its not good idea to copy the service account credential file to docker image?

Comment: You could use bind mounts or environment variables to store account credentials, or you could even use docker secrets if you are deploying on a swarm.

Comment: Please, where will you deploy the docker image?

Comment: Check out my [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62922984/5369706) for an example of a `cloudbuild.yaml` and `Dockerfile` I use to auth Google's SQL proxy. Follow that same process for your BigQuery credentials and you'll be good to go. 

The jist: build your secrets service container (I use `berglas`) and copy environment variables to use in your Dockerfile. Google Cloud Build uses the `workspace` directory and claims to wipe it out but I recommend manually deleting env vars when you're done, just to be safe none end up in cache.

Comment: Since presumably you have a Google project already, Google Secret Manager is a reasonable choice

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud-sdk image which contains `bq` cli.

https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk